# C#.NET - unable to attach the WSDL to SOAP request

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the following program written in C# to consume a web service.

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();

        obj.InvokeService(); 
    }
    public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
    {

        HttpWebRequest Req =      
         (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://MyWebService");

        Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        Req.Accept = "text/xml";

        Req.Method = "POST";

        return Req;
    }
    public void InvokeService()
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();

        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();

        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
            instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
              xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
              xmlns:soapenc=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">
             <soapenv:Header/>
             <soapenv:Body>
                <Content>..... </Content>
             </soapenv:Body>
             </soapenv:Envelope>");


             using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
             {
                 SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
             }

             using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
             {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new 
                StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
                {

                    var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

                    Console.WriteLine(ServiceResult);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
              }
           }  
        }
```

I now want to attach the WSDL to this soap request.
What I have is a .wsdl file. I tried this SOAP request using "SOAP UI" and it worked , I received the response.
It seems like I need to specify the method in the SOAP header and I am not able to do that. I can only place the .WSDL file somewhere in the project folder.

Can someone help me to get the correct response ?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not consuming the Web Service directly by adding a Web Reference pointing to the Web Service in your project...

Comment: I tried adding. It says there is an error in the XML file. And then I asked my client. He said there are 4 authentication codes that need to be appended to the request, then only it becomes success. That's why it failed

Comment: I added those 4 codes in the SOAP request. Haven't mentioned them in the post. Client does not want me to